# How to retrieve XHR response code (+timestamp) of AMD'ized Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, xmlhttprequest

With the "old" Dojo one could pass a second argument `ioargs` to the `load` function of a Xhr request ([see Example 6 here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget)). This `ioargs` provided (among other things) the timestamp and status code of the request.

But how can I achieve this with the new and "cleaner" (and forward compatible) Dojo?
Unfortunately, I could not find any hints in the [current documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/xhr.html#id5).

The following should be a port of above referenced example to the "new" Dojo. But, `ioargs` will be undefined:

```js
require( "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!",
  function(request, dom){
    // Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
    var targetNode = dom.byId("getLicenseStatus");

    // The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
    request.get(
      "{{dataUrl}}dojo/LICENSE",
      {
        handleAs: "text",
        preventCache: true
      }
    ).then(
      function(data, ioargs){
        // FIXME: ioargs is undefined
        targetNode.innerHTML = "XHR returned HTTP status: " + ioargs.xhr.status;
      },
      function(error){
        targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error.response.status + ": " + error.response.text;
      }
    );
  }
);
```

What do I need to change to have the request's timestamp and status code available in the load function?

Comment: Does the deferred produced by request.get() have the information squirreled away inside?

Comment: `request.get()` produces (as @Kniganapolke also states) a `promise` object. I can not find any data beside some function definitions and a prototype constructor in there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`request` returns a special `promise` ([source](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/08/21/introducing-dojorequest/)):

> Promises returned from dojo/request calls have an additional property not available on standard promises: response. This property is a promise that will resolve to a frozen object (where available) describing the response in more detail:
>
> - url – final URL used to make the request (with query string appended)
> - options – options object used to make the request
> - text – string representation of the data in the response
> - data – the handled data in the response (if handleAs was specified)
> - getHeader(headerName) – a function to get a header from the request; if a provider doesn’t provide header information, this function will return null.

So you should chain `.then` to this `promise.response` to get access to all the aforementioned properties:

```
var promise = request.get("{{dataUrl}}dojo/LICENSE");

promise.response.then(function(response) {
    console.log("status", response.status);
    console.log("url", response.url);
    console.log("data", response.data);
});
```

See a working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/6wB2L/

Comment: Thanks. Retrieving the status works perfectly fine with that. Though there is no possibility of getting the timestamp of the request, right?

Comment: Does not seem so, but you can add `timestamp: (new Date()).valueOf()` into request options and then you will find it in `response.options.timestamp` (see updated jsFiddle). Or consider `request/registry` to do it for you in every request.

Comment: The response object not only has the above described properties (url, options,...), but also a xhr property, which references the underlying XMLHttpRequest object.