# Ajax POST with DOJO 1.8.1

Tags: ajax, dojo

I'm try to POST data with ajax by using [DOJO(v. 1.8.1)](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/ajax/)

```
request.post("http://someweb.com/service", {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    handleAs: "text",
    sync: false
}).then(function (text) {
       console.log("The server returned: ", text);
});
```

When POST a data it doesn't show a log message in Tab Console of FireBug but shows in Tab Net instead.

[image]

**NOTE** : I'm already require `"dojo/request"` and log `on dojo ready` it's working OK. No any error.

Why it shows in Tab Net and how can I fix it? I have no idea what wrong with my code.

Comment: Is your `request.post` cross-domain? Because if so, it won't use XMLHttpRequest, but `script` tag or `iframe` transport and so it won't list as XHR.

Comment: @phusick Yes my `request.post` is cross-domain. How can I fix that?

Comment: Have a look at [`dojo/request/iframe`](http://goo.gl/FD4XT) and [`dojo/request/script`](http://goo.gl/dRNsD). If you expect plain text in return read esp. [`Content Handling`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/request/iframe#content-handling). Also, you can add another function as a second parameter to  `.then()` which is an _error handler_ as I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483149/access-http-body-on-dojo-request-error/12490183#12490183). **N.B.:** `dojo/request` returns [special promise](http://goo.gl/btP5W) to enable the access to ioArgs.