# dojo/request Ajax error data

Tags: ajax, dojo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retreive XHR response code (+timestamp) of AMD’ized Dojo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154748/how-to-retreive-xhr-response-code-timestamp-of-amdized-dojo)

When making an Ajax call using dojo/request, is there a way to get access to the response data in the error callback? Error response data will often contain formatted debug information that would be very useful to display.

I believe this used to be possible with Dojo's XHRget and it's "handler" callback.

Comment: Is [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154748/how-to-retreive-xhr-response-code-timestamp-of-amdized-dojo/12155418#12155418) what you are looking for?

Comment: @phusick I believe so, yes. Thanks.